# Is there a Java 8 syntax for collections.addAll() to work with null parameters?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list2 = null;
// throws NullPointerException
list.addAll(list2);

// using a check here    
if (list2 != null) {
    list.addAll(list2);   
}
```

Is there a `Java 8` way of doing it simple in one line?

This is one I have, but I actually don't need the `boolean` created:

```
boolean added = list2 != null ? list1.addAll(list2) : false;
```

Comment: Why does it have to be one line? `list2 == null ? Collections.emptyList() : list2`.

Comment: `if(list2!=null) list.addAll(list2);` **is** one line. It’s actually shorter than `Optional.ofNullable(list2).ifPresent(list::addAll);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specifically want a Java 8 way, you can do

```
Optional.ofNullable(list2).ifPresent(list::addAll);
```

But I don't think it wins much over the [*ternary expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator).

Answer (score 0):

Try the Optional Type new in Java 8. It is capable of dealing with null Pointers...